# Unable to send emails on task scheduler using python when "Run whether User is logged on or not" is turned on

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, win32com, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using Python script to send emails at regular intervals using Task scheduler. It was all working good, suddenly it stopped working. Now when I update settings to 'Run only when user is logged on, it's working otherwise it's failing

Comment: What does the log say for the specific Scheduled Task? If the python app is dependent on user state or interactive use it will fail without if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Thank you @IODEV for your reply .I'm seeing the opcode as (2). I don't think it's dependent on user state. all it's doing is going to extract data from multiple resources and send email once the job ends.